# How to merge two ActiveRecord objects, including associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In our Rails application, we have multiple records corresponding to the same real-world person. Assume we have unambiguously identified two matched records. I want to merge the newer record into the older record, including all the associations by calling `old_person.merge(new_person)`, where `merge` is a method on `Person`. It should work like `Hash#merge`, but recursively merge associations rather than just overwriting them.

I can hand-code the logic for this on the `Person` model using our current schema. But if it could be done dynamically using `ActiveRecord::Reflection` to traverse the graph of associations, that would be more robust and future-proof. I could even define `#merge` in a `Concern` and `include` it in all classes that inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`. That way, it might be possible for each association to call `merge` recursively on its associations.

Complications could arise in several situations I can think of: `belongs_to` or another association methods being set up wrong, options to the association methods (e.g. `scope`s), etc.

So—

1. Is there a way of doing this using a gem or built-in functionality that I'm overlooking?
2. Is there a simpler way of achieving the goal of merging records and their arbitrarily complex associations than what I'm describing, but without hard-coding association information into the `merge` method?
3. I already mentioned some complications. Are there other complications I'm not thinking of? This may not even be possible or practicable; if so, I’d be especially grateful for answers to items 1. and 2.

Comment: Your question is too long and hard to understand.

Comment: I have attempted to shorten and clarify it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you feel the need to merge 2 Active record objects?

Comment: So that we can update a person who has retaken the same questionnaire at a later time, possibly while we are aware that they are the same person, possibly only after discovering the match later. And to accept data from an outside vendor by importing data and running it through a translation layer.

Comment: Neither of those explains why you think you need to store the record in separate tables / classes. You might just be overthinking what is a relatively simple case that can be handled with a enum column or STI.

Comment: Well, for one thing, we are moving away from our Rails monolith, and so also have an API on the database not run by Rails (so STI and other Rails alchemy is harder to implement than simply having a single canonical record for each person). We also want to migrate to a standards-specified format, and the migration will be simplified by having a single record for each person. I think I'm going to hard-code the merging logic and write smoke tests against changes to the relied-on data format.